# Trying to run KIVY, for the first time, fails to load app

Tags: python, kivy

I know there has been a similar question to this but it doesn't seem to answer my problem

I have installed python and kivy and get this in pydoc modules

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/jeff/.kivy    /logs/kivy_15-04-23_10.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

When I try to run a program containing:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
```

it fails with the message

```
>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/app.py", line 316, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/base.py", line 30, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
 ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/kivy/_event.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Can someone please give me a clue as what might be wrong

Thanks

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: 64 version of python?

Comment: No, kivy. How you do that depends on your installation method.

Comment: Should I use apt-get? and what package do I enter?

Comment: See http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html. See the Ubuntu section (top)

Comment: Tried that. No mention of 64 bit. and I don't know what "Update your packagelist using your package manager" means

Comment: Solved by removing Kivy and re-installing. Thanks